# How can I create a module to allow only admins to access the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sometimes I need to block access on a website, but I don't want to block access for administrators so they should be able to see the website and for that I guess I need to make a module.

How can I make a module like that?

This is the code I have. I just don't know where I should place it.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser() as User;

if (user == null || (user != null && !user.IsAdministrator))
{
    // Block
}
```

Comment: Out of curosity can you explain why? Is this because you deployed a new version and want to do a quick test?

Comment: When I deploy I have to configure a lot of things on the running website, it takes a while to complete all tests and configurations. Meanwhile I wanted to redirect normal users to a "offline page".

Comment: Is "Administrator" a role in your membership provider?

Comment: Yes. The property I've posted already works, the problem is that I don't know where I should place this code to run on all pages (except by the "offline page")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block access to a site, or portions of a site, using web.config files to configure your directories.

As an example,

```
  <location path="/admin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*" />
                <allow role="Administrator" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

EDIT: Based on your comments above, you might be interested in the technique described at the [bottom of this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111544/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110707-1.aspx) for taking an application offline but still allowing administration access.

See the [docs on the location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) for more examples and information.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. I managed to redirect the user setting the loginUrl, like this: `<forms name=".ASPNET" loginUrl="~/app_offline_.htm" protection="All" timeout="1440" path="/"/>` on the `<authentication>` tag

Answer (score 1):

If "Administrator" is a role in your membership provider, then you can switch this on/off in the web.config.

Normal operation:

```
<location path=".">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Admin-only mode:

```
<location path=".">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```